# Enable https on Werkzeug using key/cert as Strings

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, werkzeug

Is that possible to enable HTTPS on Werkzeug based Python applications without having to use a static path to the certificate, but passing these directly as strings?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = ('cert.crt', 'key.key')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, ssl_context=context, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

I'd like to pass to the context things like this :

```
certificate = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIB9TCCAWACAQAwgbgxGTAXBgNVBAoMEFF1b1ZhZGlzIExpbWl0ZWQxHDAaBgNV
BAsME0RvY3VtZW50IERlcGFydG1lbnQxOTA3BgNVBAMMMFdoeSBhcmUgeW91IGRl
...
98TwDIK/39WEB/V607As+KoYazQG8drorw==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----'

key = '-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFDjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDg
MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAgD1kGN4ZslJgSCBMi1xk9jhlPxPc
9g73NQbtqZwI+9X5OhpSg/2ALxlCCjbqvzgSu8gfFZ4yo+
A .... MANY LINES LIKE THAT ....
X0R+meOaudPTBxoSgCCM51poFgaqt4l6VlTN4FRpj+c/Wc
blK948UAda/bWVmZjXfY4Tztah0CuqlAldOQBzu8TwE7WD
H0ga/iLNvWYexG7FHLRiq5hTj0g9mUPEbeTXuPtOkTEb/0
GEs=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

This way, it'd be easier to pass SSL data as environment value.

Answer (score 1):

For what I read through [Werkzeug code](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/532479573ab3ecd815795df58a48ae7d68777ee0/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L580), the `ssl_context` option get passed down to [`ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain), where the certfile string must be the path to a single file in PEM format. So the answer is *no*.

You could create a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) but I think you should carefully review the security implications of it.